# vba code to Adjust Loan Amount scroll bar to 10L and Tenure scroll bar to 15Yrs

Tags: vba, selenium

I want to Adjust Loan Amount scroll bar to 10L and Tenure scroll bar to 15Yrs as shows in pic1 using selenium vba.
I have also created a macro for this but this macro Adjust Loan Amount scroll bar to 13L and Tenure scroll bar to 16Yrs.
Please find the below pic1 and pic2.

My vba code:

```html
Sub tes1()
Dim Driver As New FirefoxDriver
Driver.Get "https://www.99acres.com/do/HomeLoan/"
Driver.Window.Maximize
Driver.FindElementByName("monhtly").SendKeys ("18000")
Driver.FindElementById("rangeVal1").SendKeys "10"
Driver.FindElementById("rangeVal1").Click
Driver.FindElementById("rangeVal2").SendKeys "15"
Driver.FindElementById("rangeVal2").Click
End Sub
```

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chfJX.jpg)

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtAha.jpg)

Comment: do you have a question of some kind?

Comment: Hi Jsotola thanks for the reply.Yes,want to click Loan Amount scroll bar to 10L and Tenure scroll bar to 15Yrs but i am unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust also by triggering the associated javascript onchange events by updating the values with:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AdjustSlider()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.99acres.com/do/HomeLoan/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Dim input1 As Long, input2 As Long
    input1 = 10
    input2 = 15
    html.getElementById("rangeVal1").Value = input1
    html.getElementById("homeLoanAmount").Value = 100000 * input1
    html.getElementById("rangeVal2").Value = input2
    html.getElementById("homeLoanTenure").Value = (input2 / 30) * 360

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs reference to "Selenium Type library"

[Link to download Selenium Library](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0)

```
Sub tes1()

    Dim Driver As New FirefoxDriver
    Driver.Get "https://www.99acres.com/do/HomeLoan/"
    Driver.Window.Maximize
    Driver.FindElementByName("monhtly").SendKeys "120000"


    Driver.FindElementById("rangeVal1").SendKeys "10"
    Driver.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('rangeVal1').value=10"
    Driver.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('rangeVal1').onchange()"


    Driver.FindElementById("rangeVal2").SendKeys "15"
    Driver.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('rangeVal2').value=15"
    Driver.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('rangeVal2').onchange()"

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't test this as I can no longer access the site but well done if you have solved.